# Wrong Regex Expression Matching in Python

Tags: python

I have file where I want to replace when a particular thing(string) matches with semicolon. If Equipment onsite is null/nothing then replace with semicolon, otherwise if there is anything after equipment onsite, I wanted to keep as it is.

```
import pandas as pd 
import re

data = pd.read_csv("TestEquipmentOnsite.csv", header=0) 

data = data.replace(r",Equipment onsite=", ";", regex=True) 
print(data)
```

Output generated by my python code:

[image: Output my code generating]

How I wanted my output look this:

[image: I wanted my output look this]

The problem is that my python code is completely removing Equipment Onsite thing. It is removing "Equipment onsite" string only when it is null or nothing, otherwise I wanted to keep my "Equipment onsite" string.

I know the problem in Regex expression. But I am not able to fixed it.

File attached: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jA2Kyqwa5Ug60dK51CZFdz3X2n8r5OmP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Comment: You need to provide the work you have attempted so far, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Please note that SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: @zloiGoroh, added code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Pandas:

```
df['Header2'] = df['Header'].str.replace(r'^,Equipment onsite=$', ';', regex=True)
print(df)

# Output
                           Header                         Header2
0              ,Equipment onsite=                               ;
1      ,Equipment onsize=12345577      ,Equipment onsize=12345577
2  ,Equipment onsite=SHAN123check  ,Equipment onsite=SHAN123check
```

Or without regex:

```
df.loc[df['Header'] == ',Equipment onsite=', 'Header'] = ';'
```